# nested el in jsf

Tags: jsf, el

I am having a problem with nested EL for `<t:inputText>` required Attribute. I am using tomahawk implementation.
I have a dataTable with 2 columns of inputText. I have `forceId=true` for both the inputText
boxes. When you look at view source of page, id's looks as `postal[0]` and `zone[0]` where postalCode and zone are the id's of textBox and the number 0 is the rowId of dataTable.

My requirement here is zone inputText is required only when postal is not empty.
I have written something like below which I know is not right.

```
required="#{!empty param['postalCode[#{rowIndex}]']}">
```

Can some one suggest how to do it?

Answer (score 4):

This should work:

```
required="#{!empty paramValues.postalCode[rowIndex]}"
```

The `#{paramValues.name}` returns a `String[]` with values in the indexed order.