# Resolve selectonemenu index inside p:repeat

Tags: jsf, primefaces, el

I'm trying to pass to an ajax listener the index of a combo generated inside a repeatable area, but I don't really know how to do it.

This is my code:

```
<p:repeat value="#{bean.data}" var="datas" varStatus="dataList">
    <p:outputLabel value="#{datas.key}" />
    <p:selectOneMenu widgetVar="singleData#{dataList.index}">
        <f:selectItems value="#{datas.value}"
                       var="row" 
                       itemValue="#{row.id}" 
                       itemLabel="#{row.name}"
                       />
        <p:ajax update="@form" 
                listener="#{bean.select(datas.value.get(singleData#{dataList.index}.index))}" />
    </p:selectOneMenu>
</p:repeat>
```

As you can see this code is wrong, because I cannot write `singleData#{dataList.index}.index` inside my listener. This will return the next error:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Encountered " <IDENTIFIER> "# "" at line 1, column 58.
```

How can I use the widgetVar in my selectOneMenu?

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? Why do you need that index?

Comment: I'm afraid your approach is not completely correct. Your `selectOneMenu` should map a managed bean property. Then in your listener you'll be able to read that property.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [nested el in jsf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3149848/nested-el-in-jsf)

Comment: In the real scenario I have an undefined number of `selectOneMenu` items. I don't want to have N attributes in my managed bean. With this solution I only have one method `select` that I can reuse with every combo. This is working just fine, the only issue here is to get the index of my `selectOneMenu` so I can pass to my method the object contained in the list, at the index selected..

Comment: @Kukeltje the link you posted it's something completely different. In that case they are using a dataTable, which have the property "rowIndex". My problem here is that I'm using the widgetVar to get the index, but like the name is constructed with another parameter, I cannot access it's index property with EL.

Comment: Look at the GENERIC common/shared issue (like the title of that topic states), it is about nested EL. It **IS** the solution to your problem (or at least to the first part), read it, look at what you both did wrong